# Are these two sets of density functions equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the set of density functions $$\mathscr{G}=\{ g=(1-\epsilon)f + \epsilon h\mid \mbox{h is a density function on $\Omega$}\}$$ where $f$ is a known (fixed) density function on $\Omega$, $h$ is a density function, which is a member of the set of all density functions on $\Omega$ and $\epsilon$ is also a fixed known number with $0<\epsilon<1$.

> Claim: For the set $$\mathscr{G}'=\{g'=(1+\epsilon')f'-\epsilon' h\mid \mbox{h is a density function on $\Omega$}\}$$  $\mathscr{G}=\mathscr{G}'$ with a suitable choice of $f'$, which may only be dependent on $f$ but not on $h$.
>
> Is this claim true? if yes, what is $f'$?

The idea is the following: one can get the same set either by first choosing $(1-\epsilon)f$ and adding $\epsilon h$ or by first choosing $(1+\epsilon')f'$ and then subtracting $\epsilon' h$.

Comment: The correct set building notation for your set of density functions is { (1 - e)f + eh | e in [0,1], h density function on Omega }.

Comment: Is Omega omega_1?  What is a density function?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Let $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$. The sets are correctly defined. What you suggested would not be correct. The $\epsilon$ is a fixed known number. Only the $h$ are unknown so they are making the sets with infinitely many number of elements.

Comment: So the set is { (1 - e)f + eh |  h density function on Omega }.   The way it was written did not indicate e was fixed.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I edited the question after your comment. Thanks.